# Receiving checkbox status as Yes or No on a custom form to an email template

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, phtml, html

I am new to php and html and trying my hands on the below code where I have a custom form as shown in below SS and once customer submits the form I need to get the checkbox status as 'Yes' if the checkbox is checked and 'No' if it's not checked to my email,

[image: Custom form]

Code for this form is under a .phtml file as below-

```
<p class="free-trial-wp"><input type="checkbox" placeholder="I 'd like a free trial "name="all_sizes" id="all_sizes" value="All" checked ><span></span>&nbsp; I'd like a <strong>free trial</strong></p>
```

code for email template is under .html file as per below-

```
      <!--@subject Quote/Demo Request @-->
  {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<table>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Email: {{var email}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Organistaion: {{var organisation}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Contact Name: {{var contact}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Quote For: {{var productname}}</td></tr>  
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Contact Number: {{var telephone}}</td></tr>   
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Message: {{var comment}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Free trial: {{var all_sizes}}</td></tr>   
</table> 
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Please let me know what changes do I have to make in both the files .phtml and .html to get the checkbox statuses as Yes or No. Thanks.

Comment: Could anyone please help with this?

Comment: please share the form action controller code.

Comment: Hi Madani, below is the .phtml code where checkbox is configured,

<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$productName =  parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$productName = str_replace("%20"," ",$productName);
?>

  <p class="free-trial-wp"><input type="checkbox" placeholder="I 'd like a free trial" name="all_sizes" value="All" checked ><span></span>&nbsp; I'd like a <strong>free trial</strong></p>

  <input type="submit" class="submit-form">
</div>
</form>

Comment: The code is already pasted in initial post. I only posted checkbox related code in initial post.

Comment: In which file you wrote the mail sending code.

Comment: I've already copied the mail sending code in the original post. it's .html file. Please have look at the original post and you will know.

Comment: Any luck madani?